# How do I get the coordinates of my current location in yandex mapkit?

Tags: java, android, yandex-mapkit

How do I get the coordinates of my current location in yandex mapkit ?
There is very little information on the Internet, please help, can you have projects ?

Comment: Do you try to use mapkit LocationManager https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationManager-docpage/ ?

Comment: Please give an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final double DESIRED_ACCURACY = 0;
    private static final long MINIMAL_TIME = 1000;
    private static final double MINIMAL_DISTANCE = 1;
    private static final boolean USE_IN_BACKGROUND = false;
    public static final int COMFORTABLE_ZOOM_LEVEL = 18;
    private final String MAPKIT_API_KEY = "";
    private MapView mapView;
    private CoordinatorLayout rootCoordinatorLayout;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener myLocationListener;
    private Point myLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(MAPKIT_API_KEY);
        MapKitFactory.initialize(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        locationManager = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createLocationManager();
        myLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
                if (myLocation == null) {
                    moveCamera(location.getPosition(), COMFORTABLE_ZOOM_LEVEL);
                }
                myLocation = location.getPosition(); //this user point
                Log.w(TAG, "my location - " + myLocation.getLatitude() + "," + myLocation.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationStatusUpdated(LocationStatus locationStatus) {
                if (locationStatus == LocationStatus.NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                    System.out.println("sdncvoadsjv");
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
        mapView.onStart();

        subscribeToLocationUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
        locationManager.unsubscribe(myLocationListener);
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    public void onFabCurrentLocationClick(View view) {
        if (myLocation == null) {
            return;
        }

        moveCamera(myLocation, COMFORTABLE_ZOOM_LEVEL);
    }

    private void subscribeToLocationUpdate() {
         if (locationManager != null && myLocationListener != null) {
            locationManager.subscribeForLocationUpdates(DESIRED_ACCURACY, MINIMAL_TIME, MINIMAL_DISTANCE, USE_IN_BACKGROUND, FilteringMode.OFF, myLocationListener);
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(Point point, float zoom) {
        mapView.getMap().move(
                new CameraPosition(point, zoom, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1),
                null);
    }
}
```